# How do I display a delete confirmation dialog before deleting a row in a DevExtreme DataGrid on a Razor page?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, datagrid, devextreme

I am using DevExtreme and razor pages in a Asp.NetCore web application.
I would like to inject client side delete confirmation dialog when deleting a row.
Currently I'm using an asp-action on the controller to make the call to do the delete.

I'm not sure how/where to do this in client side (cshtml file).
I assume that I'd be somehow using javascript/jquery for this?
Are there existign 3rd party open source libraries that I should use for client side dialogs/message boxes?

**DevExtreme DataGrid definition in cshtml file.**

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<Customer>()
    .DataSource(Model)
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerName);
        columns.AddFor(m => m.CustomerId).CellTemplate(
                <form asp-action="DeleteCustomer" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" value="<%- data.CustomerId %>" name="CustomerId" />
                    <input type="image" src="/icon/close.png" />
                </form>
                </text>).Caption("");
    });
```

**Server side control action code:**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCustomer(Guid customerId)
{
    // Call WebApi Service to delete row
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the datagrid has a built-in function for confirming the delete action on the client side. Might not be exactly what you were looking for but it could be a good start.

Here is the link to the demo page: https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPNetCore/Demo/DataGrid/RowEditingAndEditingEvents/